# IntelliJ PhpStorm/Idea : how to get xml configuration folder programmatically

Tags: java, intellij-idea, phpstorm, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to do a synchronisation plugin with another system, and I need to retrieve many configurations from Idea/PhpStorm such as :

- System name (IntelliJIdea / WebIde...etc)
- System version (14/80/90...etc)

And also how to buid path from macros (I dont want to create any PersistentStateComponent because my ultimate aim is to manualy parse all xml files), because I'm totaly lost with things like StoragePathMacros.APP_CONFIG (%APP_CONFIG%).

*Sorry for the very basic question but I now tried to do it for 10 hours and thank you for your help*

Comment: 1) Try asking here: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development?view=discussi 2) You may also be interested in this (in case if you have not seen it yet): http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/faq.html

Comment: 1) already done long ago, but got no answers since 2)already read, but thank you.

Comment: Just a wild thought, but couldn't you use a versioning system (cvs, svn, git, etc) where you commit the configs and check them out on each required machine?

Comment: the whole team is near 1000 developers and on different systems (depends on the developing technology such as php, python, objective C...), so it's to wide to create a trigger like that on windows/linux/mac os and also git/svn/mercurial... Currently, I manually parse xml files from config paths, but it's not the cleanest solution!